# Problema con PHP en Nextcloud con Docker-compose

Tags: php, docker, nextcloud

mi problema viene con el php de nexcloud de docker.

**Cuando intento cargar algun archivo grande o intento realizar algun cambio en el contenedor me muestra estos errores**

```
Error: Function libxml_disable_entity_loader() is deprecated at /var/www/html/lib/private/Updater/VersionCheck.php#100

Error: Function libxml_disable_entity_loader() is deprecated at /var/www/html/lib/private/Updater/VersionCheck.php#98

Sabre\DAV\Exception\BadRequest: Expected filesize of 10485760 bytes but read (from Nextcloud client) and wrote (to Nextcloud storage) 10484569 bytes. Could either be a network problem on the sending side or a problem writing to the storage on the server side.
```

- Tambien me salta el error:

```
TypeError: Unsupported operand types: int & array
```

**Os muestro dos de los errores de PHP**

```
Error: Function libxml_disable_entity_loader() is deprecated at /var/www/html/lib/private/Updater/VersionCheck.php#98
    /var/www/html/lib/private/Updater/VersionCheck.php - line 98:
 OC\Log\ErrorHandler::onError(8192, "Function li ... d", "/var/www/ht ... p", 98)
    /var/www/html/apps/updatenotification/lib/UpdateChecker.php - line 52:
 OC\Updater\VersionCheck->check()
    /var/www/html/apps/updatenotification/lib/Settings/Admin.php - line 90:
 OCA\UpdateNotification\UpdateChecker->getUpdateState()
    /var/www/html/apps/settings/lib/Controller/CommonSettingsTrait.php - line 137:
 OCA\UpdateNotification\Settings\Admin->getForm()
    /var/www/html/apps/settings/lib/Controller/AdminSettingsController.php - line 82:
 OCA\Settings\Controller\AdminSettingsController->formatSettings({ 10: [ OCA\ ... ]})
    /var/www/html/apps/settings/lib/Controller/CommonSettingsTrait.php - line 148:
 OCA\Settings\Controller\AdminSettingsController->getSettings("overview")
    /var/www/html/apps/settings/lib/Controller/AdminSettingsController.php - line 67:
 OCA\Settings\Controller\AdminSettingsController->getIndexResponse("admin", "overview")
    /var/www/html/lib/private/AppFramework/Http/Dispatcher.php - line 217:
 OCA\Settings\Controller\AdminSettingsController->index("overview")
    /var/www/html/lib/private/AppFramework/Http/Dispatcher.php - line 126:
 OC\AppFramework\Http\Dispatcher->executeController(OCA\Settings ... {}, "index")
    /var/www/html/lib/private/AppFramework/App.php - line 156:
 OC\AppFramework\Http\Dispatcher->dispatch(OCA\Settings ... {}, "index")
    /var/www/html/lib/private/Route/Router.php - line 302:
 OC\AppFramework\App::main("OCA\\Settin ... r", "index", OC\AppFramew ... {}, { section: " ... "})
    /var/www/html/lib/base.php - line 1006:
 OC\Route\Router->match("/settings/admin/overview")
    /var/www/html/index.php - line 36:
 OC::handleRequest()
```

Y el otro error es:

```
Error   PHP Error: Function libxml_disable_entity_loader() is deprecated at /var/www/html/lib/private/Updater/VersionCheck.php#100
    /var/www/html/lib/private/Updater/VersionCheck.php - line 100:
 OC\Log\ErrorHandler::onError(8192, "Function li ... d", "/var/www/ht ... p", 100)
    /var/www/html/apps/updatenotification/lib/UpdateChecker.php - line 52:
 OC\Updater\VersionCheck->check()
    /var/www/html/apps/updatenotification/lib/Settings/Admin.php - line 90:
 OCA\UpdateNotification\UpdateChecker->getUpdateState()
    /var/www/html/apps/settings/lib/Controller/CommonSettingsTrait.php - line 137:
 OCA\UpdateNotification\Settings\Admin->getForm()
    /var/www/html/apps/settings/lib/Controller/AdminSettingsController.php - line 82:
 OCA\Settings\Controller\AdminSettingsController->formatSettings({ 10: [ OCA\ ... ]})
    /var/www/html/apps/settings/lib/Controller/CommonSettingsTrait.php - line 148:
 OCA\Settings\Controller\AdminSettingsController->getSettings("overview")
    /var/www/html/apps/settings/lib/Controller/AdminSettingsController.php - line 67:
 OCA\Settings\Controller\AdminSettingsController->getIndexResponse("admin", "overview")
    /var/www/html/lib/private/AppFramework/Http/Dispatcher.php - line 217:
 OCA\Settings\Controller\AdminSettingsController->index("overview")
    /var/www/html/lib/private/AppFramework/Http/Dispatcher.php - line 126:
 OC\AppFramework\Http\Dispatcher->executeController(OCA\Settings ... {}, "index")
    /var/www/html/lib/private/AppFramework/App.php - line 156:
 OC\AppFramework\Http\Dispatcher->dispatch(OCA\Settings ... {}, "index")
    /var/www/html/lib/private/Route/Router.php - line 302:
 OC\AppFramework\App::main("OCA\\Settin ... r", "index", OC\AppFramew ... {}, { section: " ... "})
    /var/www/html/lib/base.php - line 1006:
 OC\Route\Router->match("/settings/admin/overview")
    /var/www/html/index.php - line 36:
 OC::handleRequest()
```

¿Puede por favor alguien indicarme que puedo hacer?

Comparto el docker-compose que estoy utilizando:

```
version: '3.3'

volumes:
  nextcloud-www:
    driver: local
  nextcloud-db:
    driver: local
  redis:
    driver: local
  letsencrypt:
    driver: local


services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.2
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=myemail@gmail.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - nextcloud
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:11
    networks:
      - nextcloud
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=nextcloud
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    - POSTGRES_DB=nextcloud
    volumes:
    - nextcloud-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      - nextcloud
    volumes:
      - redis:/var/lib/redis

  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      - nextcloud
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.nextcloud.middlewares=nextcloud,nextcloud_redirect
      - traefik.http.routers.nextcloud.tls.certresolver=myresolver
      - traefik.http.routers.nextcloud.rule=Host(`nextcloud.mydomain.com`)
      - traefik.http.middlewares.nextcloud.headers.customFrameOptionsValue=ALLOW-FROM https://mydomain.com
      - traefik.http.middlewares.nextcloud.headers.contentSecurityPolicy=frame-ancestors 'self' mydomain.com *.mydomain.net
      - traefik.http.middlewares.nextcloud.headers.stsSeconds=155520011
      - traefik.http.middlewares.nextcloud.headers.stsIncludeSubdomains=true
      - traefik.http.middlewares.nextcloud.headers.stsPreload=true
      - traefik.http.middlewares.nextcloud_redirect.redirectregex.regex=/.well-known/(card|cal)dav
      - traefik.http.middlewares.nextcloud_redirect.redirectregex.replacement=/remote.php/dav/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=nextcloud
      - POSTGRES_USER=nextcloud
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db
      - NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD=adminpass
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - NEXTCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS=nextcloud.mydomain.com
      - TRUSTED_PROXIES=172.18.0.0/16
    volumes:
      - nextcloud-www:/var/www/html

networks:
  nextcloud:
    external: true
```

**Adjunto unas fotos**

[Imagen error 1](https://www.imagenes-temporales.com/subidas/ver/g5Almr)

[Imagen error 2](https://www.imagenes-temporales.com/subidas/ver/r0Pzz2)

[Imagen error 3](https://www.imagenes-temporales.com/subidas/ver/Q1YDDG)

¿Pueden ayudarme por favor a recuperar mi nextcloud?
Si necesitan más información no duden en pedirla.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Un cordial saludo, Juan

Comment: parase que algo o tu código usa 2 funciones obsoletas y sobre pasa la memoria asignada ...

Comment: Gracias por el comentario Arcanis, ¿Puedes ayudarme a buscar cual es la función obsoleta?,